# DataGridViewComboBoxCell populated but will not display content

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to dynamically set a custom dropdownlist for one of my datagridview columns which I set as a ComboBoxcolumn. When I run my application I see that there are values in my cell. However, I see no values pop up in the UI.

```
private void CustomComboBoxColumns(string filter)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        DataTable dt;
        ComboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "category";
        ComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "category";
        ComboBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        ComboBoxColumn.MaxDropDownItems = 100;
        ComboBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        ComboBoxColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        ComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "category";
        ComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "category";
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert(16, ComboBoxColumn);
        for (int i = 0; i < _iprDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt = GetDataForCategory(filter);
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)_iprDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[16]).DataSource = dt;
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetDataForCategory(string filter)
    {
        DbConnection db = new DbConnection();
        string connString = db.BuildConnectionString();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string query = "Select category from cd_category where category like '%" + filter + "%' order by category";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            da.Fill(ds, "category");
            dt = ds.Tables["category"];
            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

When I attach my debugger and check ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)_iprDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[16]).DataSource = dt; there are values in my item collection it just will not display it.

Here is more code on how the datagridview is set up.

```
_iprDataGridView.DataSource = _dbHelper.Select(queryBuild.ToString(), parameters, dbConnection);

            if (_iprDataGridView.DataSource == null) return;
            // In order to display and match the PIR table values, that are requried to be in
            // a comboBox menu, we need to remove the columns that have been populated and then
            // re-add them as comboBoxs
            ConfigureDataGridView();
            ConfigureComboBoxColumns();
            ConfigureTextBoxColumns();
```

I am thinking after the ConfigureTextBoxColumns() I will create my method that will iterate through the datagridview and create a new category comboboxcolumn and insert a new comboboxcell depending on another columns value.

Here is the code for how the columns are generated for the datagridview

```
private void ConfigureComboBoxColumns()
    {
        DataGridViewHelper dataGridViewHelper = new DataGridViewHelper();
        // Columns being converted to comboboxcolumns must be removed, created, and re-inserted
        dataGridViewHelper.RemoveColumns(ref _iprDataGridView,
                                         Columns.severity.ToString(),
                                         Columns.phase.ToString(),
                                         Columns.app.ToString(),
                                         Columns.project.ToString(),
                                         Columns.acceptancePeriod.ToString(),
                                         Columns.classConfirmed.ToString(),
                                         Columns.oncall.ToString(),
                                         Columns.warranty.ToString(),
                                         Columns.release.ToString(),
                                         Columns.category.ToString(),
                                         Columns.ticketType.ToString());

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.severity.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(int);
        string query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_SEVERITY + IPRDetailsConstants.SEVERITY_COL;
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.severity.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.severity, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.phase.ToString());
        query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_PHASE + IPRDetailsConstants.PHASE_COL;
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.phase.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.phase, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.app.ToString());
        query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_APP + IPRDetailsConstants.APP_COL;
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.app.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.app, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.project.ToString());
        bool activeProjectsOnly = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ActiveProjectsOnly"));
        query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_PROJECT + (activeProjectsOnly ? IPRDetailsConstants.PROJECT_COL_ACTIVE : IPRDetailsConstants.PROJECT_COL);
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.project.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.project, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.acceptancePeriod.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = Resources.IprDetails_ConfigureComboBoxColumns_ap;
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "acceptancePeriod";
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesStatic(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.acceptancePeriod.ToString(), Resources.Y, Resources.N, Resources.S, Resources.X);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.acceptancePeriod, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.classConfirmed.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = Resources.IprDetails_ConfigureComboBoxColumns_cc;
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "classConfirmed";
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesStatic(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.classConfirmed.ToString(), Resources.Y, Resources.N, Resources.X);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.classConfirmed, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.oncall.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = Resources.IprDetails_ConfigureComboBoxColumns_oc;
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "onCall";
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesStatic(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.oncall.ToString(), Resources.Y, Resources.N, Resources.X);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.oncall, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.warranty.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = Resources.IprDetails_ConfigureComboBoxColumns_w;
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "warranty";
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesStatic(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.warranty.ToString(), Resources.Y, Resources.N, Resources.X);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.warranty, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.ticketType.ToString());
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = Resources.IprDetails_ConfigureComboBoxColumns_tt;
        comboBoxColumn.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "ticketType";
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesStatic(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.ticketType.ToString(), "I", "P", "R", "K", "Q");
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.ticketType, comboBoxColumn);

        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.release.ToString());
        bool activeReleasesOnly = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ActiveReleasesOnly"));
        query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_RELEASE + (activeReleasesOnly ? IPRDetailsConstants.RELEASE_COL_ACTIVE : IPRDetailsConstants.RELEASE_COL);
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.release.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.release, comboBoxColumn);

        /*
        comboBoxColumn = dataGridViewHelper.CreateComboBoxColumn(Columns.category.ToString());
        query = IPRDetailsConstants.SELECT_CATEGORY + IPRDetailsConstants.CATEGORY_COL;
        dataGridViewHelper.SetComboBoxChoicesDataSource(ref comboBoxColumn, Columns.category.ToString(), query, dbConnection);
        _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert((int)Columns.category, comboBoxColumn);
        */

    }
```

I commented out their column for categories to insert my own. I am updating this application which was not developed by me.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want all the combo boxes in the column to “ALL” have the “same values” OR do you want EACH combo box to have different values? Those are two different things. Having them all the same is fairly straight forward by setting the “DataGridViewComboBoxColumns” `DataSource.` This will set all the rows with the same values including any new rows.

Comment: Setting “each” cell to its own `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` will require more work on your part. This will include filling the combo box each time a new row is added. I am guessing this is what you are seeing. I do not see a `RowsAdded` event to fill the combo box when a new row is added.

Comment: Yes so I am setting each cell to its own DataGridViewComboBoxCell, and the previous person had a columns generated with the same comboboxcell for the entire column and then insert after the datagridview has been binded. I am just trying to update one column so that each cell has their own comboboxcell.

Comment: From my test, the posted code worked as expected. I am able to see the combo box values on all rows except the last “new” row. I am guessing something else is going on. Since it is not known “what” items you are putting in each combo box, I can only assume they are all completely different.

Comment: The `CustomComboBoxColumn` method adds the combo column to the grid then loops through all the rows in the grid to set each combo box. What If the user “ADDS” a new row, it doesn’t make sense to delete/re-add the combo box column then loop through all the rows again? “How” are the items in each combo box determined? We can see a “filter” string that gets the values based on that string, however, “where” is the filter string coming from?

Comment: The "filter" string will be coming from another column's selected value and I'll add more code to give some more information. After the gridview has the datasouce set I can iterate through and set each cell that way. Essentially I have one column called App which has its own combo box with options like DW, Other, Software and based on what that value is it will filter and find its relating categories such as DW-other, DW-Attunity, DW-Abend and etc. So I will need to change on cell value change event as well to update the category comboboxcell.

Comment: @JohnG I added more context

Comment: Wow. Whatever you are trying to do… it appears you are making this WAY more complicated than it has to be. Posting code that does not reproduce the problem only leads to more questions and wasted time for both parties. I recommend you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am confident if you start from scratch to ONLY reproduce the problem, you may be surprised that often the problem “reveals” itself. Without complete code that reproduces the problem... speculation is about all you may get.

Comment: I suggest you re-think using your current approach. It appears the code is “querying” the data base for each combo box. This is obvious as you need the data… however, you may not want to do this inside a cell value change event or loop. Depending on “where” this code IS… you could be setting yourself up for slamming your database for no reason. Re-querying for the same data is not really a good idea in this context, however this is speculation on my part.

Comment: How many “different filter” strings are there? Are there “duplicates”? Meaning… the column that holds the filter string… are any of those values the same? If they are, then it may be better to create and SAVE a table/list for those “duplicate” items to avoid re-querying the data base. In addition, if you create a method that sets the combo box from the ROW level give a row index or row will make it easy to loop through ALL the rows (load) or a single row on a cell value change (event). Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to bind your data to the control. After you set the source you have to bind it. See the edit I made. This link offers more information, and an example
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307860/asp-net-data-binding-overview

```
    private void CustomComboBoxColumns(string filter)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            DataTable dt;
            ComboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "category";
            ComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "category";
            ComboBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
            ComboBoxColumn.MaxDropDownItems = 100;
            ComboBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            ComboBoxColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            ComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "category";
            ComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "category";
            _iprDataGridView.Columns.Insert(16, ComboBoxColumn);
            for (int i = 0; i < _iprDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dt = GetDataForCategory(filter);
             ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)_iprDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[16]).DataSource = dt;
             ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)_iprDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[16]).DataBind(); //this edit
            }
        }
```

**I also HIGHLY recommend learning to use parameterized queries to prevent sql injections**

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not contain the definition.DataBind(). Also yes I was using parameterized queries before but for the sake of problem solving I was just using this route.